# Release Artifacts delivered to user group as an attachment in email

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I work with build and release in VSTS. I use Copy Files option in my Build definition and copy the Artifacts in a folder. I want that the Artifacts ( .exe, .dll, .zip etc)created at the end of the release must be attached in an email and must be delivered to a list of email addresses.
How this can be achieved.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve the problem on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Send Email**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) task to achieve it. Details as below:

In the end of your release environment -> Add a Send Email task -> configure required options.

To delivery the artifact files by the Send Email task, you can select the Add Attachment option and specify absolute path for the attachment:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use archive task to zip the files and use powershell script given below to send an email with attachment.

[image: How to Zip the report folder in pipeline]

Now use Powershell task and paste following script. Please edit SMTP and email settings.

```
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Username = "Youremail@gmail.com"
$Password = "Pass@1"
$to = "senderemail@gmail.com"
#$cc = "ccemail@gmail.com"
# Below subject line will have todays date and Build status as Succeed or Failed
$subject = "$(get-date -format dd-mm-yy) Automation Test report $(Agent.JobStatus)"
$body = "Your email body text"
# Enter the path of existing Archieve output folder
$attachment = "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/YourZipFolderName.zip"
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.subject = $subject
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$message.body = $body
$message.to.add($to)
#$message.cc.add($cc)
$message.from = $username
$message.attachments.add($attachment)
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$smtp.send($message)
write-host "Mail Sent successfully using GMAIL"
```

Please make sure to Use run option as "Even if a previous task has failed, unless the build was canceled" as shown below.

[image: Even if a previous task has failed, unless the build was canceled]